# React throws an error while mapping the array of objects Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, methods

I am trying to turn an array of the objects into jsx elements

```js
const CardContainer = props => {
  const { cars } = props;

  const cards = cars.map((item, idx) => {
    return (
      <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.src} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title style={{ color: 'black' }}>{item.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Get more info</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  });

return(
  {cards}
    )
};
```

However, the App crashes and thorws an error - ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {cards}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The problem is in the code *using* `cards`, which you haven't shown. From the error message, one might guess that you have `{{cards}}` where you mean to have just `{cards}`, but it's impossible to be sure without seeing the code in question.

Comment: Side note: You need a `key` attribute on those `Card` instances. If the `item` objects have a unique `id` or something, that would be your best bet. Don't use `idx` unless the `cars` array is never changed.

Comment: You need to provide full context of code.

Comment: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {cards})" - exactly what the error message says. Currently, you're returning `{ cards }`, which is an object with a property of `cards`. You need to return the `cards` array instead, so just change it to `return cards`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `{cards}` try returning simply `cards`. That should most probably solve the issue. The rest can only be identified when we have the full context of the code.

Answer (score 0):

From React v16 it's possible for render() to return an array of elements. So you can simply return cards.

```js
return cards;
```

Also don't forget to add `key` prop to mapping items.

```
<Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={idx}>
```

Comment: You don't need use `fragments`, you could just do `return cards`.